# Why wont this MySQL Query save

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this short script. Its not giving out any error but it will not save into the DB. After I run the script I check the DB and nothing is there.

The db only has two items. (id and fid) ID is set at INT 11 auto and fid is set at VARCHAR 64. Also, I am connecting to my DB just fine.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('####', '####', '####', '#####');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Failed to Connect to MySQL' . mysqli_connect_errno();
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fid = $_POST['fid'];

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM fid where fid = '$fid'");
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($row == 1) {
        echo 'This Federal Tax ID is already in use.';
    } else {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `fid` (id, fid) VALUES ('', '$fid')");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: id and empty value....

Comment: Try with `INSERT INTO fid (fid) VALUES ('$fid')` instead, and see if it makes a difference

Comment: I bet if you check for errors from the database you'll find that it's telling you exactly why it won't save.  Also, you have a SQL injection vulnerability.  So technically this query could be doing *anything* in the database.

Comment: Never trust user input...

Comment: @david could you tell me what you mean, or how to do that specifically.

Comment: @matteo It's supposed to be an empty value so the ID auto increments everytime.

Comment: @KevinMiles: `mysqli_error($con)` might be what you're looking for.  You can read more: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @David what's the vulnerability?

Comment: Table name and the column name is indentical

Comment: @KevinMiles: You're concatenating user input directly into your query.  Essentially you're executing user input *as code*.  If the user supplies a value, that's fine.  If the user decides to supply SQL code, they can run that code on your database.  Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @AmitThakur I just changed the table name too "Federal" and switched it up in the code. Still the same issue.

Comment: Add echo mysqli_error($con); to you code, this will show you the exect error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> It's supposed to be an empty value so the ID auto increments everytime.

That's not how auto-increment works.  Your code is explicitly telling the record to *not* have a value:

```
"INSERT INTO `fid` (id, fid) VALUES ('', '$fid')"
```

If the `id` column is required, this will expectedly fail.  (It may also be failing based on the type.  You're trying to insert a string, but an auto-increment column would be numeric...)

An auto-increment column doesn't need to be supplied an empty value.  Just omit it entirely:

```
"INSERT INTO `fid` (fid) VALUES ('$fid')"
```

Additionally, this code is ***wide open to SQL injection***.  You're going to want to [read up on that](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  In short, you should use prepared statements which bind to user-input values.  Don't concatenate those user-input values directly into your code, that allows the user to inject their own code.

Comment: wow, this whole time I thought I had to still put it in there even though I wanted it to be auto.

Comment: It is working now, and I will check up on the SQL injection vulnerabilities. Thank you again sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `AUTO` you need to either NOT specify the value at all or else specify a 0 (or NULL if defined as NOT NULL):

Either

```
INSERT INTO fid (fid) VALUES ('$fid')
```

or

```
INSERT INTO fid (id, fid) VALUES (0, '$fid')
```

or (if `id` is defined as `NOT NULL`)

```
INSERT INTO fid (id, fid) VALUES (NULL, '$fid')
```

SOURCE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html